# Xcode Tabs change always from code to code

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to fix a tab to one file, so it will never change.
When I debug with breakpoints, the same tab jumps from one code to another (file). Also during regular development the tab changes the content always.
In eclipse, once you have opened a file in a tab it will not change anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it's not possible to fix a tab to one file so it will never change. The equivalent tab functionality you are referring to from eclipse does not exist in Xcode.

The main functionality surrounding the use of tabs seems to be switching to them with Xcode behaviours. From looking at these behaviours in settings and seeing what you *can* do, it's clear Xcode's tab functionality is in a world of it's own.

It is possible to name a tab by double clicking the title and setting a name. (On it's own this is not very useful).

[image: Rename Tabs]

You can then use the "Show tab named [tab name] in [active window | separate Window]" option within your desired behaviour hook *category* to open (or swap to) this same tab when something happens. Behaviours are part of preferences, global to Xcode, not project specific so this is an indication that these functions are for general workflow related things.

[image]

Apart from this "open a tab named and switch to it" behaviour, your only other option to keep your existing file in it's tab (named or not) is to open new files from the navigator by selecting the file while pressing <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd> or selecting via the "Open Quickly" menu ( <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) and pressing <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> to bring up.

[image: Xcode Magic Open Menu]
<sub>(source: [git-tower.com](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/content/posts/51-6-tips-for-xcode/xcode-open-file.gif))</sub>

> These features are documented well over at [git-tower.com](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/6-tips-for-xcode/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this from the behaviors tab in Xcode preferences. Specifically check out the `Pauses` events.

Comment: I went through all the preferences and I did not recognize any option there, thats why I am asking where it is.

Comment: you can have Xcode open a new tab for breakpoints, thus leaving your original tab intact. Don't get me wrong, I find behaviors extremely limited as well..

Comment: Yes I know this. The question is, if there is a way to fix the tab forever. If its not possible its also good to know :-) I am not looking for a workaround.

Comment: I'd invite you to try writing your own Xcode plug-in to achieve the desired functionality. While it may seem overkill, it is a _great_ learning opportunity and may benefit many other devs looking for the same.